# Как устроен Ассемблер?

Tags: ассемблер

Задали изучать ассемблер, но не совсем понимаю как он устроен. Начал гуглить решение задач, но они словно написаны на ином ассемблере - не том, что нам дали. Можете скинуть материалы для изучения, а то чувствую нам недостаточно дали?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ассемблер он бывает разный, под конкретный процессор/платформу. Возможно, преподаватель сделал свой ассемблер и дает писать программы на нем (а почему бы и нет).

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что в тексте вопроса материал, который вам дали? В принципе, такого ассемблера достаточно для решения простейших задач (если не задумываться о переполнении и т.п., т.к. размер аккумулятора и операндов (как и то, это двоичный или десятичный компьютер и т.д.) я тут не увидел)

Comment: Ассемблер - это просто набор команд, которые поддерживает устройство исполнения. Обычно когда говорят об ассемблере, еще уточняют, для какого конкретно устройства эти команды используются. Можно даже придумать команды для устройства, которое физически не существует. Ваша задача, логически правильно применить последовательность этих комманд. Есть еще два определения ассемблера - это сам код и сборщик, который код превращает в машинные команды устройства. Сборщик может поддерживать свой вспомогательный набор директив. Поэтому гуглить решения особо не поможет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Приведенный Вами список команд явно не относиться к ассемблеру х86, наиболее известному и популярному ассемблеру, как следствие большинство материалов которые вы находите в сети относятся не ктому ассемблеру что вам задал преподаватель.

Какой ассемблер задал вам преподаватель и где искать для него материалы вам нужно уточнить у него.

Answer (score 4):

Как мне представляется, простейшая программа ввода 2-х целых чисел и печати их суммы на вашем ассемблере могла бы быть вот такой:

```
RC    a
RC    b
AddC  a b
SendS r
WrC   r
Stop
; описания комментариев
; и резервирования ячеек памяти
; у вас нет,
; поэтому я решил немного пофантазировать
a:    int
b:    int
r:    int
```

Что же касается материалов для изучения, то я бы порекомендовал [вот эту](http://easyelectronics.ru/files/Book/digital-design-and-computer-architecture-russian-translation.pdf) книжку.

Вот небольшая цитата из нее:

> 6.2 ЯЗЫК АССЕМБЛЕРА Язык ассемблера – это удобное для восприятия человеком представление родного языка компьютера. Каждая инструкция
> языка ассемблера задаёт операцию, которую необходимо выполнить, а
> также операнды, которые будут использованы во время выполнения. Далее
> мы познакомим вас с простыми арифметическими инструкциями и покажем,
> как эти операции пишутся на языке ассемблера. Затем мы определим
> операнды для инструкций MIPS: регистры, ячейки памяти и константы. В
> этой главе предполагается, что вы уже имеете некоторое знакомство с
> высокоуровневыми языками программирования, такими как C, C++ или Java
> (эти языки практически равнозначны для большинства примеров в этой
> главе, но там, где они отличаются, мы будем использовать C).

Answer (score 1):

Ассемблер - это не совсем обычный ЯП. Он платформо-зависим, то есть несовместим для разных аппаратных платформ. Команды в Ассемблере - это по сути прямое соответствие машинным командам (инструкциям, опкоду).
Книги по Ассемблеру можно найти [тут](https://codernet.ru/books/assembler/).

Порекомендовать для начала могу Калашников О.А. "Ассемблер - это просто. Учимся программировать." во втором издании (2011 год).

В Вашем случае, вполне возможно, что нагугленные ответы действительно написаны на "ином ассемблере", так что для Ваших задач лучше использовать те методички, что дал преподаватель. Если он адекватный, то попробуйте обратиться с вопросами. Только не "я ничего не понимаю, объясните мне всё", а по конкретным задачам, конкретные вопросы, на основании того, что есть (или чего нет) в материалах, что он дал.